# Fail to send email by utility class

Tags: apex, email-template, apex-email-service, visualforce, send-email

I have below utility class which throws error as this in debug log.

**Error**
INVALID_FIELD_WHEN_USING_TEMPLATE: When a template is specified, the plain text body, html body, subject, charset, and "treatBodiesAsTemplate" may not be specified

**Utility Class**

```
   public class AbbvieUtilitiesclass
{
    public static Map<String,String> M;
   /* public map<String, String> MyMap = new map<String, String> {'A' => 'Initial_Notification_to_Rep',
                                                            'B' => 'Initial_Notification_to_Manager_Publish',
                                                            'C' => 'Notify_DM_Manager_on_Incident_Closure',
                                                            'D'=> 'Reminder_Notification_to_Manager_and_RM',
                                                            'E'=>'Notify_Rep_on_Incident_Closure'};*/

        public static void sendTemplatedEmail(String[] toRecipients, String[] ccRecipients,Boolean CCCheck, String templateApiName) {
      //  templateId   must be ID of an Email template
      //  targetObjId must be a Contact, User, Lead Id -- also used in merge fields of template recipient.xxxx
      //  whatId    must be an SObject that is used in the merge fields of the template relatedTo.xxxx
      //  fromId    if non null, use current user, otherwise, use this ID (most likely an org wide no reply id)
      //  bcc      not permitted when using templates
     List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > mails = new List < Messaging.SingleEmailMessage > (); 
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

    Emailtemplate template;  
    try {template = [select Id, Subject, HtmlValue, Body, name from EmailTemplate where developername = : templateApiName];}
    catch (Exception e) {
      /*throw new UtilException ('[U-03] Unable to locate EmailTemplate using name: ' + templateApiName + 
                    ' refer to Setup | Communications Templates ' + templateApiName);*/
    }


       // String htmlBody = Template.HtmlValue;

   // htmlBody = htmlBody.replace('{!}', 'Dear '+toRecipients );

        email.setToAddresses(toRecipients);
        if(CCCheck==true && templateApiname!='Initial_Notification_to_Manager_Publish')
       { email.setCcAddresses(ccRecipients);}
       // email.setTargetObjectId(targetObjId);
        //email.setWhatId(whatId);
       // email.setorgWideEmailAddressId(orgWideEmailId);
        email.setSubject(template.name);
       // email.sethtmlbody(htmlbody);
        //email.setTargetObjectId(targetid);
         email.settemplateid(template.id);
        email.setSenderDisplayName('Abbvie IT Team');
        email.SetSaveAsActivity(false);
      //  email.setSaveAsActivity(saveAsActivity);      // save email as activity on the targetObjId (i.e. Contact). Note activity can't be saved on Users

       /* System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,'** entered sendTemplatedEmail, to:' + toRecipients + ' cc:' + ccRecipients +  ' templateId:' + templateId + ' tagetObjId:' + targetObjId + 
                        ' whatId:' + whatId + ' orgWideEmailId: ' + orgWideEmailId);*/
        try {
            mails.add(email);
            Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
            return;
        }
        catch (EmailException e) {/*throw new UtilException('[U-02] sendTemplatedEmail error. ' + e.getMessage());*/} 

    }     

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove this line

```
 email.setSubject(template.name);
```

as error clearly  says **When a template is specified, the plain text body, html body, subject, charset, and "treatBodiesAsTemplate" may not be specified**

I also think you should uncomment this lines if you are using Template.

```
//email.setTargetObjectId(targetid);
```

Comment: Then how to put Subject of the Email? Will it default take Email template Name?

Comment: It works! Now it says "REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Missing targetObjectId with template:" But I dont know why and how to set it? Is it necessary?

Comment: I have already update my answer. Please check and yes it is necessary for template and it will take default subject.